# Foreign Key From two tables in one column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have a `order` table and each order in that table belongs to either a `device` or `part` (these two have no specific intersection in fields).
So I need to store the `did` or `pid` as FK in `order` table.

```
"device"
+----+....
| id |<---------+
+----+....      :
: : : : .       :
                :
                :
"part"          :
+----+....      :
| id |<-------+ :
+----+....    : :
: : : : .     : :
              : :
              : :
     "order"  @ @
     +-----+-------+....
     | id  |  for  |....
     +-----+-------+....
     : : : : : : : : .
```

Now How should I do this?

- Add a `type` field to `order` table and store both `pid` or `did` on
  one column(e.g. `for`)
- Create an intermediate view with
  `type`,`pid`,`did` columns
- Create a higher level table (e.g.
  `goods`) and make its PK to be FK on `order`,`part`,`device`

Which one is the best method? or some other method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895147/database-design-or-relation/2897732#2897732
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050784/defining-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-many-tables/4051523#4051523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use **exclusive foreign keys** or **inheritance**, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120). Just be careful about CHECK, which is [not enforced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/533120) by MySQL, so you'll have to "emulate" it via trigger.

Please don't do the "type" approach, it can lead to [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with two tables, one for the order and the other for item. Item table will have ID, type (part or device; P or D) and the rest of the details. In the order table, I will just have a FK to the Item Table ID.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would create both the following FK fields: `did` and `pid`.  You would always have a value for one and not the other.

Your query would look something like the following:

```
SELECT o.*, COALESCE(p.descr, d.descr) AS Description,
            COALESCE(p.number, d.number) AS PNumber
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN device d ON o.did = d.id
LEFT JOIN part p ON o.pid = p.id
```